# How to support Flash images and flash video's in ios programatically

Tags: ios, ipad

For ex : I am loading an url which contains an flash image ,which is not loading in ios .

Another one is i am loading a video of .flv format , how to support this in ios ?

Comment: [Step 1: be a seasoned iOS hacker who makes Android libs run on iOS.](https://github.com/comex/frash)

Answer (score 0):

The web view does not support .swf files, but there are libraries that will render .swf files for iOS:

[SwiffCore](https://github.com/musictheory/SwiffCore)

SwiffCore wasn't even the one I was thinking of. There's some C library also. The popular game Clash of Clans renders .swf assets in the game.